# Animating uniform motion

Tags: animations

I want to build an animation with two points in uniform motion next to each other. Both would be going back and forth on an axis from x=-243 and x=125. The speed of the points is the same, but they start moving at x=0 and go in different directions. How can can I start writing a code for this?

Comment: Welcome! For something like what you describe it would be easier to just use Desmos. // Additionally, TeX is primarily used for typesetting _static_ documents. You are probably asking for help with one of the graphics utilities often used in conjunction with TeX, such as TikZ or asymptote. You may wish to make this question more focused by specifying which utility/language you are considering, as well as what output format you are looking for.